# Resources overwriting when gradle build

Tags: android, resources

During the build, resources inside the library are overwritten. The names of the resources in the library are unique, with a prefix. The debug shows that in the end there are resources of the wrong type and I get a crash: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0700c2 type #0x4 is not valid`. As a result, where the resources of my library should be, there are the resources of the material library: [image]. Gradle version: 7.6